# ExecuteReader- An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the above mentioned error everytime I try to run this particular web page. I am adding some code and an image of the database structure (given as a link). In the additional information line of the error, it says there has been attempt to read data when the data table is empty. When I go back to check the table data, there is data present. Please help!

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkdu = "select Top 1 Hour, Minute, Hour1, Minute1 from Clockin";
    SqlCommand cmddu = new SqlCommand(checkdu, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dru = cmddu.ExecuteReader();
    int td1 = (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Hour"]) * 60) + (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Minute"]));      //error shown here[enter image description here][1]
    int td2 = (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Hour1"]) * 60) + (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Minute1"]));
```

Comment: Please don't include your connection string. Sometimes it may contain confidential data. It may not hurt you if it is just a test project, but its good practice while posting on platforms like SO

Comment: @RachitGupta thank you for the suggestion, I have made the edit and will keep this in mind in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`SqlDataReader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) to advance the reader to the next(first) record:

```
using(var dru = cmddu.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(dru.Read())
    {
        int td1 = (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Hour"]) * 60) + (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Minute"]));      //error shown here[enter image description here][1]
        int td2 = (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Hour1"]) * 60) + (Convert.ToInt16(dru["Minute1"]));
    }
}
```

[Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default position of the SqlDataReader is **before the first record.**
>   Therefore, you must call Read to begin accessing any data.